# Google Meet high CPU usage on Firefox 78

Tags: windows-10, firefox, cpu

I'm using Windows 10 build before build 2004 and Firefox 78.0.2, and Google Meet uses almost 100% of my Core i5 8th generation for the duration of the meeting. If the windows if minimized the CPU usage decreases by 20%. Hardware acceleration (VT-d) is enabled, with the latest drivers for the videoboard Intel 620 installed. Any ideas if it's a Windows problem, a Firefox problem or a Google problem?

Comment: Google has an issue with Chrome with high CPU usage. I see that on my machine and have seen some news articles about this. Try Google Meet using Edge Chromium and see if that works better.

Comment: I only have Firefox available on this machine.

Comment: Windows has Edge built in, so you can try legacy Edge for sure.

Comment: This is a corporate machine and only Firefox is allowed. In any case, this does not solve the issue, and at least point where the issue is, so I can report it